# prestashop 1.7 css file displayed depending on url address

Tags: css, url, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to make a mechanism that will display the css file depending on the url address

example
if url = [www.domain.com/our.php](http://www.domain.com/our.php) then we print `<style> background: red; </style>` if not, `<style> background: blue; </ Style>`

chciałbym to umieśćić między `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop you can do this stuff directly in your template files, you have many helper variables available:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/displaying-content-in-front-office

search for "Here is a list of Smarty variables"

You can load extra styles here:
/themes/your_theme/templates/_partials/head.tpl

You can do for example:

```
{if $page.page_name == 'product'}
{literal}<style>body { background: red !important; }</style>{/literal}
{/if}
```

This will result with a red background on product page.